# Performance problems w/ many widgets respectively stacked QTableWidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to display a complex Table and decided to use stacked QTableWidgets. With an increasing number of rows the program needs a lot of time for creating all the widgets and almost the same time for displaying.

The maintable looks like this: MainTable

[image]

The stacked TableWidget in the table:

StackedTables

[image]

if the cell contains data, there is at least one TableWidget in one cell of the MainTable and in the worst case there are 2 more TableWidgets in that one. That means I could have 3 TableWidgets in one cell.

Time measurement with cProfile and time.time for 80rows (with 48 of the complex cells for each row):

```
complete update time: 15s (manually stopped)
time to create the table: 7.548534870147705s (time.time over complete function)
display time: 7.5s (complete update time - function time)
rows: 80

     63600 function calls in 7.462 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1896    2.455    0.001    3.882    0.002     DigitalePlanungstafel.py:6054(grundWidgetErstellen) -- (create table in cell)
 3936    2.027    0.001    2.027    0.001 {built-in method setCellWidget}
 2535    1.306    0.001    1.306    0.001 {built-in method setColumnCount}
  630    0.770    0.001    1.183    0.002 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:6035(obenWidgetErstellen) -- (create table in table in cell)
 2607    0.674    0.000    0.674    0.000 {built-in method setRowCount}
 2528    0.059    0.000    0.059    0.000 {built-in method horizontalHeader}
 2526    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {built-in method verticalHeader}
  163    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 {method 'execute' of 'sqlite3.Cursor' objects}
 2526    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {built-in method setFrameShape}
 1410    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {built-in method setStyleSheet}
 4502    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {built-in method setRowHeight}
 2526    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method setFixedSize}
 2546    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method setColumnWidth}
 5052    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {built-in method setVisible}
 1329    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method setItem}
 2181    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {built-in method cellWidget}
   80    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method addWidget}
 2526    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method setEditTriggers}
  929    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method setBackground}
 1330    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
  414    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method _pickle.loads}
  336    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}
 2526    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy}
 1410    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method setFixedHeight}
 1377    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method setTextAlignment}
   83    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 _strptime.py:321(_strptime)
    2    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {built-in method setSortingEnabled}
 2526    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setShowGrid}
 1570    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method rowHeight}
 2526    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setSelectionMode}
  163    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'fetchall' of 'sqlite3.Cursor' objects}
  240    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:7494(__init__)
 2526    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setVerticalScrollBarPolicy}
    1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method sortByColumn}
   80    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setLayout}
   83    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method _locale.setlocale}
    1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method _sqlite3.connect}
   89    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setForeground}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 _strptime.py:562(_strptime_datetime)
   48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setHorizontalHeaderItem}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setContentsMargins}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method strptime}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 locale.py:379(normalize)
   88    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setFont}
  160    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setData}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'groupdict' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setAlignment}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 _strptime.py:29(_getlang)
   83    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 locale.py:565(getlocale)
   83    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 locale.py:462(_parse_localename)
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setUnderline}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
  249    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of 'sqlite3.Connection' objects}
  160    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method item}
  742    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:7499(__lt__)
   48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method today}
  165    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'toordinal' of 'datetime.date' objects}
  475    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
  167    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  166    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'end' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   84    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
   47    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method columnCount}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'weekday' of 'datetime.date' objects}
   96    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}
   20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method columnWidth}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _locale._getdefaultlocale}
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _strptime.py:284(_calc_julian_from_U_or_W)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _bootlocale.py:11(getpreferredencoding)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method sortIndicatorOrder}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'cursor' of 'sqlite3.Connection' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'index' of 'list' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method fromordinal}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method sortIndicatorSection}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:259(__init__)
```

The time for calling the function and creating the Table is okay but the program needs almost the same time again until it reacts.

The Goal would be to reduce the update time by approx. 50%. I need to display around 200 rows.

Is the stacked QTableWidget the right approach - If so what do I have to do to optimize the update times?

I already thought about changing the presenatation from QTableWidget to a QGraphicsView and simply drawing the rectangles. 
Or maybe a combnation, for example: Using the QTableWidget for the Header and the first columns and then merging all the complex cells and inserting a QGraphicsView but I am not sure if I am able to get the right size for the drawed cells and I do not know if the displaying time will be shorter.

What do you guys think is the right approch for a table like this?

If you need I can append the function, which is updating the Table.

**EDIT:**

I am using now 2 rows in the MainTable for one Block which reduced the number of stacked widgets from 2.526 to 7!

The time measurement for the same rows now looks like this:

```
complete update time: ~2s (manually stopped)
time to create the table: 0.572490930557251 (time.time over complete function)
display time: ~1.5s (complete update time - function time)
rows: 160
     20912 function calls in 0.534 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 1417    0.258    0.000    0.258    0.000 {built-in method setCellWidget}
   88    0.209    0.002    0.209    0.002 {built-in method setRowCount}
  163    0.017    0.000    0.017    0.000 {method 'execute' of 'sqlite3.Cursor' objects}
 1410    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {built-in method setStyleSheet}
   80    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {built-in method addWidget}
 1336    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method setItem}
    7    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.001 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:6037(obenWidgetErstellen)
  501    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method _pickle.loads}
 1990    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method cellWidget}
  336    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}
   83    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 _strptime.py:321(_strptime)
 1330    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
 1410    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method setFixedHeight}
  929    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setBackground}
 1377    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setTextAlignment}
  240    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:7452(__init__)
  163    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'fetchall' of 'sqlite3.Cursor' objects}
   16    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setColumnCount}
  770    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setSpan}
 2127    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method item}
 1570    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method rowHeight}
   80    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method setLayout}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _locale.setlocale}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _sqlite3.connect}
  167    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setRowHeight}
   89    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setForeground}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
   48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setHorizontalHeaderItem}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 _strptime.py:562(_strptime_datetime)
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method takeItem}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setContentsMargins}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method strptime}
   88    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setFont}
  160    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setData}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 locale.py:379(normalize)
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setAlignment}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 _strptime.py:29(_getlang)
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'groupdict' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 locale.py:565(getlocale)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of 'sqlite3.Connection' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method horizontalHeader}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setUnderline}
  249    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 locale.py:462(_parse_localename)
   48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method today}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method verticalHeader}
  475    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
  167    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  165    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'toordinal' of 'datetime.date' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
  166    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setFrameShape}
   27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setColumnWidth}
   84    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'end' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
   87    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 DigitalePlanungstafel.py:6059(<lambda>)
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setFixedSize}
   14    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setVisible}
   83    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'weekday' of 'datetime.date' objects}
   96    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setEditTriggers}
   20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method columnWidth}
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _locale._getdefaultlocale}
```

The updateing time is more than good but I have 2 problems because of the splitting.

1. Sorting (over the header) is not working anymore. This is caused by the merging, it messes up everything. Is there a way to freeze two associated rows before sorting?
2. I only want one row to be selected at a time. Cause of the splitting I need to select the two associated rows no matter which one gets selected. Not really a big deal but doesen´t really look good (see pictures).

[MainTable selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLLlb.png)

[MainTable selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/235G5.png)

Comment: In order to have a fast performing GUI you definitely need to use `QTableView` (with a model) instead.

Comment: You need to explain much more clearly exactly ***why*** you are using tables within tables like that. Are you just using them as a quick and dirty way of doing complex formatting in the cells? If so, a much better approach would be to use [item-delegates](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes), which can then paint the cells directly. That would also allow you to use custom editing widgets, If the cells aren't read-only.

Comment: I am using the tables within tables because its the only approach that I was able to manage for the complex formatting. The cells are read only  (NoEditTriggers). I am a beginner in Python and QT - thats why I don t rellay want to make it too complex. At the moment my idea is to use 2 rows instead of one and merge the first 6 rows, that should reduce the stacked tables by a lot - I will let you know how much faster it will be as soon as I am done.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do any of this - instead:

1. Use a model for your data.
2. Use a viewmodel that adapts the model to the view you wish to have.
3. Use a `QTableView` to display the viewmodel.